# Is there a showcase for richfaces 5?

Tags: jsf, richfaces, demo

http://showcase5-richfaces.rhcloud.com/ mentioned on http://www.bleathem.ca/blog/2013/06/richfaces-500alpha1-release-announcement.html is down, so I've been wondering whether this temporary or on purpose and whether there is an alternative which I didn't find after a default search engine query.

Comment: You missed this event? http://www.bleathem.ca/blog/2014/07/richfaces-will-pursue-stability-over-innovation.html Posted just 5 days before your question.

Comment: @BalusC I don't understand how you mean that? What event? How does the blog entry you linked relate to my question?

Comment: RichFaces stops. There will be no 5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I asked a question about that in the [topic](http://www.bleathem.ca/blog/2013/06/richfaces-500alpha1-release-announcement.html) you referred. Maybe Brian will respond.

But in any case, you can build and deploy showcase yourself. E.g. it's packaged in `example` folder of distributions, latest can be found here: http://richfaces.jboss.org/download/nightly